# Is it possible to only update one field?

Tags: apex, trigger, fields, dml, update

Is it possible to only update one field?

```apex
List<Account> accountsFromSF = [SELECT Email_3__c from Account LIMIT 50];
for (Account acc : accountsFromSF){
    acc.Email_3__c = 'test@gmail.com';
}
update accountsFromSF;
```

I have required fields and some validation rules for some fields..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a validation would prevent saving the record, you cannot save the record, even just to update one field. You would need to fix the data or disable the rules in Setup beforehand.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible to update only one field if all the data meets the defined conditions.
But sometime While updating the field if the particular record, missing the required field then error will occur while updating.